# Is OData suitable for multi-tenant LOB application?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, search, odata

I'm working on a cloud-based line of business application. Users can upload documents and other types of object to the application. Users upload quite a number of documents and together there are several million docs stored. I use SQL Server.

Today I have a somewhat-restful-API which allow users to pass in a DocumentSearchQuery entity where they supply keyword together with request sort order and paging info. They get a DocumentSearchResult back which is essentially a sorted collection of references to the actual documents.

I now want to extend the search API to other entity types than documents, and I'm looking into using OData for this. But I get the impression that if I use OData, I will face several problems:

- There's no built-in limit on what fields users can query which means that either the perf will depend on if they query a indexed field or not, or I will have to implement my own parsing of incoming OData requests  to ensure they only query indexed fields. (Since it's a multi-tenant application and they share physical hardware, slow queries are not really acceptable since those affect other customers)
- Whatever I use to access data in the backend needs to support IQueryable. I'm currently using Entity Framework which does this, but i will probably use something else in the future. Which means it's likely that I need to do my own parsing of incoming queries again.
- There's no built-in support for limiting what data users can access. I need to validate incoming Odata queries to make sure they access data they actually have permission to access.

I don't think I want to go down the road of manually parsing incoming expression trees to make sure they only try to access data which they have access to. This seems cumbersome.

My question is: Considering the above, is using OData a suitable protocol in a multi-tenant environment where customers write their own clients accessing the entities?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is suitable here. Let me give you some opinions about the problems you think you will face:

> There's no built-in limit on what fields users can query which means
>   that either the perf will depend on if they query a indexed field or
>   not, or I will have to implement my own parsing of incoming OData
>   requests to ensure they only query indexed fields. (Since it's a
>   multi-tenant application and they share physical hardware, slow
>   queries are not really acceptable since those affect other customers)

True. However you can check for allowed fields in the filter to allow the operation or deny it.

> Whatever I use to access data in the backend needs to support
>   IQueryable. I'm currently using Entity Framework which does this, but
>   i will probably use something else in the future. Which means it's
>   likely that I need to do my own parsing of incoming queries again.

Yes, there is a provider for EF. That means if you use something else in the future you will need to write your own provider. If you change EF probably you took a decision to early. I don´t recommend WCF DS in that case.

> There's no built-in support for limiting what data users can access. I
>   need to validate incoming Odata queries to make sure they access data
>   they actually have permission to access.

There isn´t any out-of-the-box support to do that with WCF Data Services, right. However that is part of the authorization mechanism that you will need to implement anyway. But I have good news for you: do it is pretty easy with QueryInterceptors. simply intercepting the query and, based on the user privileges. This is something you will have to implement it independently the technology you use.

My answer: Considering the above, WCF Data Services is a suitable protocol in a multi-tenant environment where customers write their own clients accessing the entities at least you change EF. And you should have in mind the huge effort it saves to you.